# Buttons next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons and I want to put them next to each other. How could I do it? Everytime a button is under the other. Here's the code:

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">

.button_example{
border:1px solid #B7B7B7; 
text-align: center; 
color: #FFFFFF; 
background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.button_example:hover{
border:1px solid #B7B7B7; 
text-align: center; 
color: #1f1f1f; 
background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style></head>
```

and the **HTML**:

```
<div align="right"><a href="http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/rules.html"><input type="button" class="button_example" value="Rules" /></a></div>
<div align="right"><a href="http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/info.html"><input type="button" class="button_example" value="Info" /></a></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't put `<input />`, inside an `<a>` tag. Also, remove the surrounding `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first - you have mess in your HTML part:

```
<div><a><input/></div></a>
<div><a><input/></div></a>
```

You should have:

```
<div><a><input/></a></div>
<div><a><input/></a></div>
```

At second – if you want clickable button why don't use a `<button>` tag instead of `<a><input></a>`?

And the final. Try add this style to your div's:

```
float: right;
```

But you need add some `clear` item after this. For example:

```
<br class="clearFloat">
```

and css

```
.clearFloat { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out the **[jSFiDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/3DzsM/)**

remove the extra div tag and enclose both a tag under one div tag

like this:

```
  <div align="right">
    <a href="http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/rules.html"><input type="button" class="button_example" value="Rules" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/info.html"><input type="button" class="button_example" value="Info" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do 3 things:

1. remove the `align="right"` and replace it with `float:right`.
2. Remove the extra `<br>` inside your code.
3. Add div with css `clear:both` after you finish your buttons.

**[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/bszfm43q/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove 2 div's, use only one div and add the CSS as provided below:

```css
#butn{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="butn" align="right">
    <a href="http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/rules.html"><input type="button" class="button_example" value="Rules" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.theamazingmonth.pusku.com/info.html"><input type="button" class="button_example" value="Info" /></a>
</div>
```